# breakable in \NewTColorBox - does not compile

Tags: tcolorbox, break-box

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Example and Solution
%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
\tcbset{%
    colback=white,
    tikz={opacity=0.1,transparency group},
    colframe=black,
    title filled=false,
%   bookmark={Q\arabic{\tcbcounter}}
}
\NewTColorBox[
    auto counter,
    number within=section
    ]{example}{ +O{}mo }{%
    fonttitle    = \bfseries,
    breakable,
    title        = {Example~\thetcbcounter:~ #2},
    before lower = {\textbf{Solution~\thetcbcounter:\quad}},
    lowerbox     = invisible, %invisible/ignored
% after title/after upper
    IfValueTF={#3}{after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{\texttt #3 }}}{},
    #1
}%



\begin{document}

\begin{example}
test
\end{example}


\end{document}
```

How could I change, so that I can use the `breakable` function from the `tcolorbox` package.

At the moment, it does not compile and gives an error:[image]

Comment: You already include `breakable` in `NewTColorBox`, so where is the problem? If you want to see how it breaks, just add some more text inside.

Comment: @Ignasi It cannot compile, which gives an error...sorry I wasn't clear. I will edit.

Comment: That's surely due to your terminal being set up to use Comic Sans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please place the option `breakable` in `\tcbuselibrary`, e.g.

```
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
```

Modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Example and Solution
%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
\tcbset{%
    colback=white,
    tikz={opacity=0.1,transparency group},
    colframe=black,
    title filled=false
%   bookmark={Q\arabic{\tcbcounter}}
}
\NewTColorBox[
    auto counter,
    number within=section
    ]{example}{ +O{}mo }{%
    fonttitle    = \bfseries,
    title        = {Example~\thetcbcounter:~ #2},
    before lower = {\textbf{Solution~\thetcbcounter:\quad}},
    lowerbox     = invisible, %invisible/ignored
% after title/after upper
    IfValueTF={#3}{after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{\texttt #3 }}}{},
    #1
}%



\begin{document}

\begin{example}
test
\end{example}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It compiled without any problem. But I am not sure whether it's due to lots of "floats" (figures) in my boxed or something else. It does not seem to `break` anything... maybe I will ask in a seperate problem. Thanks.